# Xamarin iOS app not working on device because of ProgressLabel

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying run a Xamarin iOS app on a device with Visual Studio. However I get the following error:

> Error MT4116: Could not register the assembly 'Xamarin.Auth.iOS':
>   error MT4118: Cannot register two managed types
>   ('Xamarin.Controls.ProgressLabel, Xamarin.Auth.iOS' and
>   'Xamarin.Controls.ProgressLabel, Xamarin.Auth') with the same native
>   name ('Xamarin_Controls_ProgressLabel'). (MT4116)

The ProgressLabel class seems to be defined in Xamarin.Auth.iOS and Xamarin.Auth twice.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?